# Mail sending in php

Tags: php, email

I have to file to send mail.

First one is html file.

mailhtml.php

```
<form action="mailsend.php" method="post">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

  <label for="Email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

  <label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
  <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="20" id="message"></textarea>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Second is mailsend.php

```
<?php
       try{
       $name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
       $email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
       $message = htmlentities($_POST['message']);

       // set here
       $subject = "Contact form submitted!";
       $to = 'test@test.com';

       $body = <<<HTML
$message
HTML;

       $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
       $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

       // send the email
       if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
       {
            echo "success";
       }
       else
       {
        echo "Not Success";
       }
       }
       catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

Mail send successfully but my html data is not render in mail. It is look like same as i insert in textbox. See image.Thats i received in mail. [image]

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer instead. They'll make it far easier for you.

Comment: its because of `htmlentities($_POST['message']);`

Answer (score 2):

Please first note that this form allows a potential attacker to use your site to spam other people. You do not sanitize the $_POST values properly, you only strip tags from them, so it is possible to add custom headers.

For exemple, if I were to post to your form with

```
  $_POST['email'] = "spam_target1@domain.com\r\nCC: spam_target2@domain.com, spam_target3@domain.com, spam_target3@domain.com, ...
```

I would be able to mass-spam a list of users using your server.

Please make sure to strip any new lines (`\n`) and carriage return (`\r`) from the values you receive before using them in a mail header.

As for your actual encoding issue, you are using `htmlentities($_POST['message']`, so the message you are sending has all it's html tags converted to text entities (eg `<` becomes `&lt;`)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the message isn't properly formatted.   Make sure you include a doctype and  tags

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
your message here
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nick said, be sure to add the DOCTYPE and other tags, but also your `htmlentities($_POST['message'])` is converting your < and > to `&lt;` and `&gt;`

As per [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) in the PHP documentation.